# Algorithm for filling in numbers in series

Tags: algorithm, vb6, dao

I have a Recordset obtained by the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Number] FROM NUMBERS WHERE CODE = 7 ORDER BY [Number]
```

The Recordset will therefore be a list of ordered numbers, eg. [6,14,37,59,81,145]

I would like to generate a long string of numbers made up of only 0s and 1s, where it is all 0s except in positions designated by the numbers in the recordset: eg. 6,14,37,59, etc.

The result would therefore look something like:

```
000000000000000000100000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000 etc
```

Assuming that `rs` is the Recordset, I have the following code so far.  Would this work?

```
intLower = 1
While Not (rs.BOF Or rs.EOF)
    intUpper = rs!Number
    For intSlot = intLower To intUpper
        strOutput = strOutput & IIf(rs!Number = intSlot, 1, 0)
    Next intSlot
    rs.moveNext
    intLower = intUpper + 1
Wend
```

Note: I realise this is similar to an earlier question of mine, but I am now asking how to do this when the numbers are contained in a Recordset. Also note that I do not want to use a function that converts a recordset to an array, because I am using DAO and apparently the GetRows is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about;

```
dim value as long
dim result as String

do while not rs.EOF
    value = rs!Number
    If (value > Len(result)) then result = result & String$(value - Len(result), "0")
    Mid$(result, value, 1) = "1"
    rs.moveNext
loop
msgbox result
```

Edit as they are sorted;

```
dim result as String

do while not rs.EOF
  result = result & String$(rs!Number - Len(result) - 1, "0") & "1"
  rs.moveNext
loop
msgbox result
```

Comment: Are you understanding the problem properly? The result would be something like: 00000000000000001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000001 etc.

Comment: For an rs of `3, 4, 5, 8, 10` the output of the above would be the string `"0011100101"` isnt that what your after?

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic, but why do have the If statement - are you not relying on rs being sorted?

Comment: I didn't register the fact they were ordered

Comment: OK, pop in a `rs.MoveNext` and I'll award the answer.